# java.lang.ClassCastException cause by JPQL session bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jpql

I am trying to create a remote service containing JPQL but I am getting this error for the simplest query.

In my authentication service:

```
@Override
public Users checkDatabase(String email) {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u from Users u WHERE u.nom = :email", Users.class)
            .setParameter("email", email);
    Users user = (Users) query.getSingleResult();
    return user;
}
```

and my client code looks like:

```
String jndiName = "Petroca-ear/Petroca-ejb/AuthenticationServices!com.esprit.services.AuthenticationServicesRemote";
Context context = new InitialContext();
AuthenticationServicesRemote proxy = (AuthenticationServicesRemote) context.lookup(jndiName);
System.out.println(proxy.checkEmail("test@s"));
Users user = (Users) proxy.checkDatabase("peter");
```

while executing this, I am getting this error:

```
false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ProtocolMessageHandler.readAttachments(ProtocolMessageHandler.java:55)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.InvocationExceptionResponseHandler$MethodInvocationExceptionResultProducer.getResult(InvocationExceptionResponseHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:276)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBObjectInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(EJBObjectInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:290)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBHomeInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(EJBHomeInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:290)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:290)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(ReceiverInterceptor.java:129)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:265)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:453)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:202)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.checkDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at TEST.testPetroca.main(testPetroca.java:23)
```

Comment: those are client's logs, any error logs on the server side ?

Comment: No Error log from the server everything is deployed and up and running with no issue, EntityManager.persist() do its job perfectly, data can be added and deleted from mysql database fine.

Comment: I even changed to a table with one that has no relation to other table, filled it with dummy data but had the same error. I think the error is due to bad use of generics, or trying to downcast (e.g. Object -> String) to an incompatible type

Comment: check if you're using JDK1.8 ?

Comment: @Walid my current envirement is set like so: 

java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: Are you running your client from an application deployed to a java-ee server, or from a local client? `TEST.testPetroca.main` smells like a local test program. You need to follow the (WildFly I assume) [documentation](http://docs.wildfly.org/16/Developer_Guide.html#EJB_invocations_from_a_remote_client_using_JNDI) on making remote EJB calls from a standalone client.